# After Intsall SSL on magento site

Tags: ssl, magento, magento-1.9, mixed-content

I installed SSL certificate for my magento store and set system config to:

> Use Secure URLs in Frontend:yes 
> Use Secure URLs in Admin:yes

however when I review the page source some links have `http://` instead of `https://`

I cleaned up the cache, but was not able to solve this issue, can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fix your theme's templates, styles and extensions.

Search in projectroot for `href="http://` or `src="http://` and replace by `href="//` and `src="//`

also make sure external resources support ssl